# c - scanf not storing input properly

Tags: c, string, io

My code looks like this:

```
int nameFull;
printf("What is your name?\n");
scanf("%d\n", &nameFull); \\up until here it seems to work
printf("Hello %d", nameFull);

return 0;
```

But my output every time I run the program is "Hello 0" no matter what I input.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `int nameFull;` --> `char nameFull[64];`, `scanf("%d\n", &nameFull);` --> `scanf(" %63[^\n]",  nameFull);` (or use `fgets`), `printf("Hello %d", nameFull);` --> `printf("Hello %s\n", nameFull);`

Comment: Offhand, the only time I've ever heard of a person with a numeric name was in fiction  (7 of 9 in Star Trek: TNG).   For most folks, the name will need to be represented using a character string, not an integer.

Comment: Before using any C standard function (like `scanf` or `printf`) you should read some [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) about it.

Comment: @gsamaras scanf with `%s` stops readong on whitespace; however the name `nameFull` suggests they may want a "full name" which can include spaces

Comment: If you enter "12" for name, what is the output? If it is `Hello 12` then everything is ok. If you want to enter non-numeric characters, then read about `%s`. BTW, there is no need from `\n` in `scanf`.

Comment: how can an integer possibly be a full name?   Suggest something similar to: `char fullname[30];  ... if( 1 != scanf( "%29s", fullname ) ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for fullname failed\n" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Answer (score 2):

First of all `scanf()` doesn't emit a prompt so its not a good idea to use any trailing whitespace character in the format string like `\n` here , It will cause it to read and discard character until next non-whitespace character.

To read a name you can do it like :

```
char name[50];
scanf("%49s",name); // 49 to limit the buffer input to prevent buffer overrun , this is a security issue.
```

You should also check the return value of `scanf` to see if the operation was successful. Personally , I don't prefer using `scanf()` at all because of various potential problems. It takes as input only what the program author expects it to, not considering other inputs which user might accidentally input. Check out [here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~zachary/isp/tutorials/io/io.html)  and [here](http://www.giannistsakiris.com/2008/02/07/scanf-and-why-you-should-avoid-using-it/). Also check the [scanf() man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

A better and safer method would be use [fgets()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html),

```
fgets(name,sizeof(name),stdin);
```

Comment: to avoid a input buffer overrun, the call to scanf() should have a format string like: "%49s"  AND should be checking the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: @user3629249 A good point! I in fact prefer not to use scanf() at all , its very error prone and so I even discourage it to others.

Answer (score 1):

> `%s` reads a string of characters.
>
> `%d` reads a integer.

So, your correct code will be like following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char nameFull[100];
    
    printf("What is your name?\n");
    
    scanf("%99s", nameFull); //to avoid potential buffer overflow
    
    printf("Hello %s\n", nameFull);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**N.B:** Check this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46386863/c-scanf-not-storing-input-properly/46387216?noredirect=1#comment79813906_46387216) for nice explanation.

Comment: Consider using `scanf("%99s", nameFull)` to avoid potential buffer overflow

Comment: not my vote, but someone seems to insist on overflow protection for `scanf()`. Try editing your answer.

Comment: ok @chqrlie. I edited my answer from your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46386863/c-scanf-not-storing-input-properly/46387216?noredirect=1#comment79733115_46387216). Thanks a  lot for find out my mistake.

Comment: You might also test the return value of `scanf()` to avoid calling `printf` if the conversion fails: `if (scanf("%99s", nameFull) == 1) { printf(...); }`

Answer (score 1):

You want to read a string, but you are an integer to store the input. That's not the right approach.

A better aproach would be to use an array of characters, to store the string in it.

```
char nameFull[100]; // can store up to 100 characters, 99 + 1 for the null-terminator ideally
```

Now, you could use scanf, like this:

```
scanf(" %99[^\n]", nameFull);
```

Note that I used `99`, as a guard for not overflowing your array `nameFull`, if the user inputs too many characters for the size of your array. I didn't use `%s`, which would stop at a whitespace, and you seem to want to input a full name, which is usually two words and a space in between.

An alternative would be to use [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/), which provides more safety, like this:

```
fgets(nameFull, sizeof(nameFull), stdin)
```

It will read the whole line though and store the trailing newline, while [`scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) will read a single string.

Moreover, use the string identifier to print, not the integer one (`%s` is for string, `%d` is for integers). Like this:

```
printf("Hello %d", nameFull);
```

to this:

```
printf("Hello %s", nameFull);
```

as discussed about the string format.

Answer (score -1):

Well, int stores a number, a name is not a number. A name is a set of characters (aka strings). So this program would work (no error checking and such since you are in an introductory course):

```
char name[1024]; // 1024 is more than enough space for a name
scanf("%s", name); // %s reads a string of characters
printf("Hello %s\n", name);
return 0;
```

Comment: Downvoted for not having overflow protection in `scanf`.

Comment: kk genius @user694733, when you are dealing with a beginner its best to give as little and straight-forward code as possible so they can understand the basics before moving onto the secure version, but meh I really don't care

Comment: Using plain `"%s"` is as bad as using `gets`, which was removed from latest C standard. There is also return value chek that should be done, but using width limit is the bare minimum that every `scanf` answer must have. With little effort you can [edit] your answer, and improve it.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to assign an *array of character* (commonly referred as *string*) to an *integer* variable.

That's not correct.

Just change your variable as such

```
char nameFull[1024] = {0};
```

And then use `scanf(3)` with the appropriate format specifiers for strings, which is `%s`

```
scanf("%s", nameFull);
```

Normally you would check for the return of scanf to know if errors occurs, and in such cases, handle them.

Anyway, I would advice you to use [`fgets(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) which prevents buffer overflow

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in the buffer.

Comment: You can prevent buffer overflow with `scanf("%1023s", nameFull)`. `scanf()` read a single word whereas `fgets()` reads a full line of text including the trailing newline.